# trying to use relative locator in selenium with python but it I get 'locate_with' is not defined error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to interact with a web element in selenium, I've located a nearby element, the element I want to interact with is to the right of the located element so i tried using the relative locator to do so:

`sbJct = driver.find_element(locate_with(By.XPATH, "//span[@role='combobox']").right(term)) webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(sbJct).click(sbJct).perform()`

When i execute i get

> NameError: name 'locate_with' is not defined

I think I may be missing an import but I'm unsure

```
    from selenium import webdriver
# webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in fact missing an import, the documentation doesn't mention this but u have to use

> from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with

to use locate_with()